# Converting machine learning code in python to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, machine-learning, pickle

I've implemented a machine learning model using scikit-learn in python. Since I want to use this code in a browser (as I'm developing a chrome extension and want the application to work completely in the client side), I'd like to convert the same code to javascript.

This is my python code :

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

input_ = 'input string'
logreg = pickle.load(open('logreg.sav', 'rb'))
count_vectorizer = pickle.load(open('count_vectorizer.sav', 'rb'))
count_test = count_vectorizer.transform(pd.Series(input_))
result = logreg.predict(count_test)
print(result)
```

Code mostly involves loading the trained models saved as a pickle file. Is it possible to convert this to javascript or should I try implementing ML models in javascript again ?

Answer (score 0):

*A different approach (If you really don't want to implement the model again with Javascript)*

**Make a Django server** and render your model's **prediction using REST API**, then you could **host that site** into any free hosting services such as Heroku.
Then you could easily **access your model** from Javascript by simply **doing an API call**.